# YiiStrap not working on Yii 1.1.16?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, frameworks

Im new to use Yii framework. And I wonder how can I make bootstrap work together with Yii. Followed instructions from getyiistrap.com

I don't get any error but I cannot make the bootstrap work. I know because I test it in Yii Skeleton page. Buttons class is not working

**config/main.php**

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../extensions/bootstrap');


// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(

    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Web Application',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // path aliases
    'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'), // change this if necessary
        'vendor.twbs.bootstrap.dist' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'),
    ),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'bootstrap.components.*',
        'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
        'bootstrap.helpers.*',
        'bootstrap.widgets.*'

    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'password123',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
            'generatorPaths' => array(
                'bootstrap.gii'),

        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(

        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi'),


        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        /*
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        */

        // database settings are configured in database.php
        'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),

    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'email@network.com',
    ),

    'theme' => 'bootstrap', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory

    //not sure whats this for? dont even have a theme folder inside yiistrap-master I downloaded from getyiistrap.com

);
```

**layouts/main.php**

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="language" content="en">

    <?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>

    <!-- blueprint CSS framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/print.css" media="print">
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection">
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/form.css">

    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" id="page">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></div>
    </div><!-- header -->

    <!-- mainmenu -->
    <?php 
    $model=new LoginForm;
    if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
        ?>
        <div id="mainmenu">
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Manage User', 'url'=>array('/user/admin')),
                array('label'=>'Payroll', 'url'=>array('/user/payroll')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                // array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        )); ?>
    </div><!-- mainmenu -->
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <div id="mainmenu">
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            ),
        )); ?>
    </div><!-- mainmenu -->
        <?php
    }
    ?>


    <?php if(isset($this->breadcrumbs)):?>
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
            'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
        )); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->
    <?php endif?>

    <?php echo $content; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="footer">
        Copyright © <?php echo date('Y'); ?> by My Company.<br/>
        All Rights Reserved.<br/>
        <?php echo Yii::powered(); ?>
    </div><!-- footer -->

</div><!-- page -->

</body>
</html>
```

**views/site/index.php**

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>

<h1>Welcome to <i><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></i></h1>

<p>Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application.</p>

<p>You may change the content of this page by modifying the following two files:</p>
<ul>
    <li>View file: <code><?php echo __FILE__; ?></code></li>
    <li>Layout file: <code><?php echo $this->getLayoutFile('main'); ?></code></li>
</ul>

<h1>--- *BOOTSTRAP STARTS HERE* ---</h1>

<?php echo TbHtml::muted('Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris nibh.'); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::em('Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.', array('color' => TbHtml::TEXT_COLOR_WARNING)); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::em('Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.', array('color' => TbHtml::TEXT_COLOR_ERROR)); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::em('Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis.', array('color' => TbHtml::TEXT_COLOR_INFO)); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::em('Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.', array('color' => TbHtml::TEXT_COLOR_SUCCESS)); ?>

       <?php echo TbHtml::button('Default'); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::button('Primary', array('color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::button('Danger', array('color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_DANGER)); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::button('Warning', array('color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_WARNING)); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::button('Success', array('color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_SUCCESS)); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::button('Info', array('color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_INFO)); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::button('Inverse', array('color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_INVERSE)); ?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::button('Link', array('color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_LINK)); ?>


<p>For more details on how to further develop this application, please read
the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/">documentation</a>.
Feel free to ask in the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/">forum</a>,
should you have any questions.</p>
```

**Here's the image of what I get: *Bootstrap not working.***
Image Link: http://postimg.org/image/l98l6ovjh/

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Working now..

I added cdnUrl in config/main.php

```
'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',  
            'cdnUrl'=>"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/", 
        ),
```